# Can't use Facebook real-time updates webhook with self-signed ssl certificate

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I'm trying to setup a `callback_url` with facebook's real-time updates webhooks on my local machine. However, it is requiring me to use SSL. Annoying for develoment, but whatever. I setup a self-signed certificate, and now facebook complains about that:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#2200) callback verification failed: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2200,
    "fbtrace_id": "ak9ii3432"
  }
}
```

Is there no easy way to develop this locally without paying for a trusted SSL certificate and going through that hassle?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091202/facebook-real-time-updates-2200-callback-verification-failed-code-2200

Comment: @peeldog no, it doesn't. I am able to access my server just fine.

Comment: You are able to access your server... but is your server able to be "reached from outside"

Comment: @peeldog, yes. I verified this using a domain name and computer outside my network.

Comment: @LordZardeck were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @bubakazouba I was able to solve the problem. Sorry for the late reply. Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to solve the problem, but I just got around to documenting it as I came across the issue again (got to love using Facebook Real-time Webhooks).

Solution was to utilize [No-IP](http://www.noip.com/) in coordination with [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) to provide static access to my local server with SSL domains.

I wrote an article on my blog explaining it: https://templeton.io/local-facebook-real-time-api/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. You need a valid SSL certificate and an self-signed won't work. Please think about this, even for testing, Facebook is going to send information out to an external server so there is a need for Facebook to automatically validate that server. I understand this can be annoying but necessary for security reasons.

Please consider using services as heroku, which provide a subdomain with a valid SSL certificate you can use for your tests (and maybe even to host your production App if you like it)